# Problem working with RF 433 receiver

Tags: raspbian-stretch, remote

I'm trying from weeks to get the SRX882 receiver working with RaspberryPI with no chance.

I've bought SRX882 in addition to STX882 but cannot find a way to get them working. I've tried using RFSwitch with no success..no signal received from the receiver.
Could someone help me getting it work? 
Connection schema of receiver is: VCC->+3.3V, GND-> GND, DATA -> PIN2(WiringPI), CS (disconnected)

On some Arduino's site I read that "Connect Arduino PIN 7 to ground in order to disable an internal pullup on the RF data pin." but I was not able to activate it on RPI,cannot receive any data at all

Comment: you cannot receive data if you are not transmitting data

Comment: I am trasmitting...the STX882 or my car Controller is on the same Freq..no result on RFSniffer

Comment: `no result on RFSniffer`  .... does not mean there is no RF being detected?  ...... please provide a detailed connection diagram ...... what is the purpose of CS and why did you decide to leave it disconnected?

Comment: According to http://www.nicerf.com/Upload/ueditor/files/2016-08-29/SRX882%20datasheet%20V2.0-54b1c2d6-b433-4af6-ad75-527961adf70b.pdf CS should be set to logic 1 for normal operation.  So I guess you need to strap it high.

Comment: I already try connecting directly the CS PIN to +3.3V but the result is the same...No signal received at all.. I'm using RCSwitch

Comment: Can you see any data with [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html)?

Comment: Not in RX's GPIO PIN, I can see only datas on TX GPIO PIN (when data are sent)

Comment: Disabling internal resistance on RPI make me see data on PiScope..no data on RFSniffer..we are close to the problem I think :)

Comment: Resolved all is Working now. the only thing to do is disabling internal resistance of RaspberryPI with command `gpio mode <PIN> tri`

Comment: The internal resistors are only 50k and shouldn't affect the radio module.  It sounds like you have a problem with your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

"CS (disconnected)"  generally stands for "chip select". 
Its purpose is to allow having more than one device on common path, thus "connecting " to selected device on the bus. 
It is commonly connected to output pin and activated by grounding it.
Check you receiver datasheet to make sure about the activation level.